# Is there a way to watch for the keyup event when editing a resource via Chrome's dev tools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm creating a Chrome extension that allows people to edit the same resource at the same time via Chrome's inspector.  Right now things are only synchronized upon saving via `chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.onResourceContentCommitted.addListener` but it would be nice to replicate each other's actions in real-time.

And since it's related, I should probably also ask if it's even possible to programmatically update the resource (as shown within Chrome's dev tools) so that changes can be reflected.  I suppose I could force a redownload of the resource, but diffing and applying patches would be much more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont believe there's an API for realtime changes, no.

You can use `resource.setContent` for updating things. Take a look at the fb-flo project or Emmet LiveStyle alpha for implementation.

Comment: Cool, thanks!  I was considering using `System.delete` and then `System.define`, but `resource.setContent` seems like it would add some more flexibility in terms of when the code is ran (though I haven't checked it out yet).

Comment: Also, would it be possible to create an extension that extends the inspector itself rather than the main window, since the inspector is essentially its own page(s), using HTML/CSS/JS, importing native libraries, etc.?  I understand there are methods designed for adding panels, buttons, etc., but it would be cool to be able to extend the functionality of say, the default text editor (CodeMirror).

Comment: we're considering those sorts of extension points. nothing available right now but hopefully soon.